# Finding position of result

Tags: excel-formula

I have a worksheet looking at football results. I have inserted a formula to discover the longest sequence of blank cells which indicates to me how many games between either wins/draws/defeats. Taking wins as an example which I have in Column H, this formula (The cells in Column H contain either a 1 or are blank)

{=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(H1:H5077="", ROW(H1:H5077)), IF(H1:H5077=1, ROW(H1:H5077))))}

has told me that the longest sequence without a win for the selected team was 19 matches. That formula and result on my workbook is in cell H5094

What I want to do is discover where amongst 5000+ matches that sequence is?

I've tried this formula which I've used before in an adjacent column and copied down

=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(H2,0,0,$H$5094,1),1)=$H$5094,"here","")

however it hasn't worked. I think the mistake is within the formula, possibly the 0 and 1 but I don't know how to put it right, I've tried several variations.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The method looks fine to me, but the easiest way would be to use COUNTBLANK instead of COUNTIF, so the formula would be:-

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(H2,0,0,$H$5094,1))=$H$5094,"here","")
```

or alternatively

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(H2,0,0,$H$5094,1),"")=$H$5094,"here","")
```

I noticed that you could get some extra 'heres' if the longest sequence came at the end of the range, but you could fix it by putting a '1' in H5078.